# How to have nested query with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, csv

i am not good in LINQ but when i try to compose a linq query then getting Error.

```
void Main()
{

    var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\test.csv");     
    var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray());


    var users = csvLinesData.Select(data => new User
    {
                CSRName = data[12],
                Incomming = csvLinesData.Count(w => w.direction='I'),
                outgoing = csvLinesData.Count(w => w.direction='O')
    }).ToList();
    users.Dump();
}

class User
{
   public string CSRName;
   public string CallStart;
   public string CallDuration;
   public string RingDuration;
   public string Direction;
   public string IsInternal;
   public string Continuation;
   public string ParkTime;
    public string Incomming;
}
```

these two line causes the error

```
Incomming = csvLinesData.Count(w => w.direction='I'),
outgoing = csvLinesData.Count(w => w.direction='O')
```

i am trying to read a csv file which has many data. i just like to show data after reading from csv file

### my data should look like

```
CSR Name    Incomming       OutGoing
---------   ---------       ----------
Wills           5                9
Wills           21               74
Wills           44               45
Wills           54               2
Wills           15               20
```

if i need to draw the above output then what should be right LINQ query. looking for help. thanks

### EDIT 1

i change the code bit as follows

```
void Main()
{
    var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"M:\smdr(backup08-06-2015).csv");   
    var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray());

    //int iDir = csvLinesData.Count(w => w.direction='I');
    var users = csvLinesData.Select(data => new User
    {
                CSRName = data[12],
                Incomming = csvLinesData.Count(w => w[4] == "I"),
                outgoing = csvLinesData.Count(w => w[4] == "O")
    }).ToList();
    users.Dump();
}

class User
{
    public string CSRName;
    public int outgoing;
    public int Incomming;
}
```

but still getting error and error msg is **Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'**

where i am making the mistake ? please rectify. thanks

Comment: You mention an error - what is it?

Comment: Fyi, `l.Split(',').ToArray()` is redundant since `String.Split` already returns an array. `Enumerable.ToArray()` will create a brand new array for no reason.

Comment: Error i got as follows "'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'direction' and no extension method 'direction' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)"

Comment: i just do not understand why people just love to give negative marks. if possible give answer or do not touch.

Comment: Your `User` class (as seen here) does not contain an `outgoing` property. Is that something you missed while posting the question?

Comment: @Mou yeah right why would it have? You have array of arrays, how would it automatically associate your fields? You need something like `w => w[1] == 'I'`

Comment: @pep yes i missed that.

Comment: i am very weak in LINQ so anyone can post right linq code for my scenario like what kind of output i am expecting.

Comment: @Mou look your problem has absolutely nothing with LINQ. Structure is correct, your problem is that you need to understand what data you operate with. You operate over raw data (array of arrays). Either you use indexes, or you do mapping yourself or use some library like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Comment: please see my EDIT portion and guide me why still error is coming?

Comment: @Mou Incomming and Outgoing are string fields. Count returns an int. You are assigning an int to a string field, as the error tells you.

Comment: yes u r right and i fixed it.

Comment: I added another part to my answer. It's still not clear what you actually want to do. What exactly do you need to count as `Incoming` and `Outgoing`? Currently you get the same numbers for every user. I assume there is some grouping required. Explain clearly what you need to do or provide sample data.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray());
```

produces an `IEnumerble<string[]>`. When you select it, you can access the columns of your CSV, as you do in this line:

```
CSRName = data[12],
```

The problem with this line:

```
csvLinesData.Count(w => w.direction='I')
```

is that an element of `csvLinesData` is a `string[]` which doesn't have a `direction` field or property.

Anyhow, it looks strange that you count all the lines with a specific property, because it would result in the same number for every "user".

Because I don't know what you actually want to do (I can't even guess), I cannot tell you what to do.

---

Edit, based on new section in the question:

You cannot assign an integer to a string:

```
Incomming = csvLinesData.Count(w => w[4] == "I"),
```

Either change the property `Incomming` to an integer or create a string from the number (Which is probably not what you need):

```
Incomming = csvLinesData.Count(w => w[4] == "I").ToString(),
```

By the way, it **still cannot work**, because you count all the lines where column 5 `== "I"`, which leads to the same number for each user. Your example has a different number in each line (but the same user name). This is very confusing. You really have to think about what you actually want to do and either explain it clearly or provide some example data.

Comment: this lines `int iDir = csvLinesData.Count(w => w.direction='I');
int oDir = csvLinesData.Count(w => w.direction='O');` giving problem. error is "System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'direction'" but CSV file has one field called direction.........then why the error is coming?

Comment: what should be right approach to fetch data from csv file by linq but only like to pull data based on few condition.